# Proving convergence of two recursion sequences related to each other

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recursion

I have a question that I got troubled with and hope for some help.

> Let $p_n=(x_n,y_n)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be a sequence of vectors. It is given that $p_1=(1,0)$ and the following recursions:$$\displaystyle x_{n+1}=\frac{3x_n-\sqrt{3}y_n}{4} \qquad ; \qquad y_{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{3}x_n+3y_n}{4} $$
>   Find $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}p_n$.

I assumed that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L_1 \ ; \ \lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=L_2$ and solved the system of equations. My assumption was the the sequences converge, but I don't know how to show it. Also, I don't know if my way of finding the limit assuming that it exists is valid.

I will appreciate any kind of help. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know some linear algebra ? Do you know about matrices ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, I do, but I don't know how it could help me in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vector form we have
$$\pmatrix{x_{n+1}\cr y_{n+1}\cr}
  =\frac14\pmatrix{3&-\sqrt3\cr \sqrt3&3\cr}\pmatrix{x_n\cr y_v\cr}$$
which we can write as
$${\bf p}_{n+1}=A{\bf p}_n\ .$$
By recursion,
$${\bf p}_{n+1}=A^n{\bf p}_1\ .$$
There are various ways of evaluating the power $A^n$ - look up **diagonalisation of matrices** if you have not yet studied it - but in this case it is not too hard to prove, for example by induction, that
$$A^n=\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\Bigr)^n\pmatrix{\cos(n\pi/6)&-\sin(n\pi/6)\cr \sin(n\pi/6)&\cos(n\pi/6)\cr}\ .$$
Hence
$${\bf p}_{n+1}=A^n\pmatrix{1\cr0\cr}
  =\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\Bigr)^n\pmatrix{\cos(n\pi/6)\cr \sin(n\pi/6)\cr}$$
and you can now easily work out $x_{n+1}$ and $y_{n+1}$ and see what happens when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You can also put $z_n=x_n+iy_n$. One verify easily that $4z_{n+1 }=(3+i\sqrt{3})z_n$. Hence $\displaystyle |z_{n+1}|=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|z_n|$, and we finish easily.